# Get the evaluation of if statements in Python pdb

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, pdb

I am new to pdb. I use `python3 -m pdb myscript.py` in the command line interface. I am currently using `s` to trace code step by step. There are many if statement in the code that I want to know what they are evaluated to while tracing.

The way I am doing now is `p if-statement-that-I-am-interested-in` to print them out. This works fine when the if statement is short but gets intimidating when the line is long. **Is there a way to print out the evaluated results of if statements without efforts?** Or should I look into other tools for the purpose?

I am currently copying these statements if they are too long.

Thanks in advance.